# Выделение памяти под указатель в csharp

Tags: c++, c#

Здравствуйте, ситуация такова: есть dll библиотека на С++, и проект на С#, к которому подключена эта библиотека. В этой библиотеке есть метод 1-го класса, который в качестве аргумента принимает строку `char *`. Я создал unsafe метод , в котором стал писать что-то подобное: `char * str = new char[length]` , но есть 1 проблема компилятор не может привести тип `char []`(который возвращает new) к `char*` . То есть вопрос в том, как в С#  вернуть тип `char*` . Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с неуправляемыми библиотеками нет необходимости в unsafe коде. В данном случае достаточно объявить параметр `extern` метода, имеющий тип `char *`, как `string` или `StringBuilder`. Во время вызова среда автоматически выполнит маршалинг. Для типа `string` среда по умолчанию применяет атрибут `[In]`, для `StringBuilder` - `[In, Out]`, что позволяет изменять строку в неуправляемом коде.

Важно обратить внимание на кодировку: `char` является однобайтным в С++ и двубайтным в CLI, поэтому стоит явно указать кодировку при объявлении метода, например:

```
[DllImport("SomeLibrary.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern void Foo(string value);
```

Подробнее про вызов функций из неуправляемого (С++) кода можно [почитать на MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/26thfadc.aspx). Также: про [маршалинг различных данных](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fzhhdwae.aspx); про [маршалинг строк](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e8w969hb.aspx) в частности.